# How do I deploy my REST API on an EC2 Instance

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Im having some problems deploying my REST api written in C++ on an EC2 instance.

specifically, in my code I do the following:

`server.setEndpoint("http://ec2-18-135-114-10.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:6502");`

Which calls the function (a wrapper for the cpprestsdk):

```
void BasicController::setEndpoint(const std::string & value) {
        uri endpointURI(value);
        uri_builder endpointBuilder;

        endpointBuilder.set_scheme(endpointURI.scheme());
        if (endpointURI.host() == "host_auto_ip4") {
            endpointBuilder.set_host(NetworkUtils::hostIP4());        
        }
        else if (endpointURI.host() == "host_auto_ip6") {
            endpointBuilder.set_host(NetworkUtils::hostIP6());
        }
        endpointBuilder.set_port(endpointURI.port());
        endpointBuilder.set_path(endpointURI.path());

        listener = http_listener(endpointBuilder.to_uri());
    }
```

However, I receive the exception `URI Must contain a host name'

Ok, so I try it again with an elastic public IPv4 address:

`server.setEndpoint("http://18.135.114.10:6502/");`

Again, I get the same error - no host name.

The only case I can get working is on local host, which looks like

`server.setEndpoint("http://127.0.1.1:6502:6502/");`

Note, this file shows how the exception arises from the cpprestsdk library https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/src/http/client/http_client.cpp

This is probably a very silly question, so I appreciate an kind person giving their help

Comment: Have you tried with `server.setEndpoint("http://host_auto_ip4:6502/");` ?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, I tried that, and that works, but that just makes the API listen on the private IPv4 address of the server, which of course cannot be accessed publicly. I should have clarified sorry

Comment: If you expose http over the internet, everything will be in plain text insecure. Maybe its better to put api on localhost only, then setup nginx as reverse proxy to provide https support?

Comment: @Marcin you're correct, and I would, but this is not for anything serious, just a proof of concept.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind to check is to use instance public dns name, rather then ip.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that was what I tried in the very first example.

Comment: Oh. Missed that. Sorry.

Comment: @Marcin I have found a solution, below. Thanks for just thinking things through with me

Comment: No problem. So what was the issue? you already tried using instance dns which did not work?

Comment: @Marcin, No it was that when using the `uri_builder`, I never extracted and set the 'host' field from the passed in value. It was a matter of adding a final `else` to the if..elseif

Answer (score 1):

Solution, change the function  to:

```
void BasicController::setEndpoint(const std::string & value) {
        uri endpointURI(value);
        uri_builder endpointBuilder;

        endpointBuilder.set_scheme(endpointURI.scheme());
        if (endpointURI.host() == "host_auto_ip4") {
            endpointBuilder.set_host(NetworkUtils::hostIP4());        
        }
        else if (endpointURI.host() == "host_auto_ip6") {
            endpointBuilder.set_host(NetworkUtils::hostIP6());
        }
        else {
            endpointBuilder.set_host(endpointURI.host());
        } 
        endpointBuilder.set_port(endpointURI.port());
        endpointBuilder.set_path(endpointURI.path());

        listener = http_listener(endpointBuilder.to_uri());
    }
```

and use

```
server.setEndpoint("http://ec2-18-135-114-10.eu-west2.compute.amazonaws.com:6502/");
```